# How to optimize this kind of code in Java?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, pojo

I need to optimize some Java code, which "converts" ~100 POJOs of one type to POJOs of another type.

Suppose, for example, there are POJOs `A1` and `A2`. and there is a function `A2 convert(A1 a)`, which *creates* a new instance of `A2` and *copies* data from the given `a` to it. Suppose also I have a function `Collection<A2> convert(Iterator<A1> as)`, which works with collections of ~100 objects.

How can I make this `convert` run faster. Can I optimize the new instance creation in `convert` ?

Comment: how fast your code runs depends on the code in the convert method

Comment: Did you think to optimize it by using concurrency?

Comment: If instance creation is the bottleneck, doesn't sound like you need to  optimize anything. Profile the method to see what's actually taking time (if indeed there is a performance issue) and then tell us the results. No reason to poke around in the dark trying to make things go faster.

Comment: Profile first, don't guess.

Comment: Do you _need_ new instances. If you are simply using an `Iterator` to loop over types of `A1` and process them using as `A2` consider using a facade pattern or a flyweight pattern.

Comment: You are converting *a hundred* instances? Have you measured the actual time it takes? My bet: 1 microsecond.

Comment: if you knew the to be collection size, initiate with the exact size to avoid memory swapping cost.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to parallelize it to use CPU efficiently.

Another way is to make `convert` faster. A combination of the two techniques will give you faster code.

On the other hand you can try to use some sort of inheritance between `A1` and `A2` and just cast it(this is from guess work, I don't know how your code is exactly)

Answer (score 2):

You can get drastic improvements when you do multiple conversions in parallel. Java has great features for this. Take a look at the Thread class to get started.